# How to send multiple messages with xmpphp

Tags: php, xmpp

As the title says, i want to send the same message to multiple recipients. I use the PHP library XMPPHP and send single messages with this:

```
<?php
include("xmpp.php");
$conn = new XMPP('talk.google.com', 5222, 'username', 'password', 'xmpphp', 'gmail.com', $printlog=False, $loglevel=LOGGING_INFO);
$conn->connect();
$conn->processUntil('session_start');
$conn->message('someguy@someserver.net', 'This is a test message!');
$conn->disconnect();
?>
```

I try it with a loop of this:

```
$conn->message('someguy@someserver.net', 'This is a test message!');
```

Or a loop with the complete code. But nothing happens...

Best regards,

Hannes

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `$conn->message('someguy@someserver.net', 'This is a test message!');` line in the loop.

The code before this line makes the connection and waits for the xmpp session starting.

The code after this line makes the disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you  need to destroy $conn after your disconnect(); before you use it again if its in a loop?

Or give each $conn a unique name?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that someguy@someserver.net (the person you are sending to) has username@gmail.com (the account you are sending from) added as a friend.

Answer (score 0):

Servers have a limit of how many messages you can send per time frame. If you send a bunch of messages in a loop, i presume you'll hit that limit pretty fast. Try with http://php.net/sleep